# Resolve many to many relationship in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgresql. Let's say I have 3 tables:

```
Classes
id | name
1  | Biology
2  | Math


Students
id | name
1  | John
2  | Jane


Student_Classes
id | student_id | class_id | registration_token
1  |          1 |        1 |                abc
2  |          1 |        2 |                def
3  |          2 |        1 |                zxc
```

I want to obtain a result set like this:

```
Results
student_name | biology | math
        John |     abc |  def
        Jane |     zxc | NULL
```

I can get this result set with this query:

```
SELECT
  student.name as student_name,
  biology.registration_token as biology,
  math.registration_token as math
FROM
  Students
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT registration_token FROM Student_Classes WHERE class_id = (
    SELECT id FROM Classes WHERE name = 'Biology'
    )
  ) AS biology
  ON Students.id = biology.student_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT registration_token FROM Student_Classes WHERE class_id = (
    SELECT id FROM Classes WHERE name = 'Math'
    )
  ) AS math
  ON Students.id = math.student_id
```

Is there a way to get this same result set without having a join statement for each class? With this solution, if I want to add a class, I need to add another join statement.

Comment: I think you have to use `Join`, since in RDBMS, their relationships are maintained by constraints, but relationships actually make sense when JOINing with related tables.  In your case it is better to design tables in your way for a better scalability. Yes it is tedious to keep joining when you need to add a new table. Try to review your design of table before implementing, but accept what relational database theory give you.

Comment: Use [refcursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN63396) to [construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN63237) your query at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via postgresql tablefunc extension crosstab but such presentation requirements may be handled better outside of sql.